# The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<DrinksTwitter>) is undefined

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting the following error:

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, 
                       Class<DrinksTwitter>) is undefined
```

In the following code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the EditText and Button References
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
    lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    // Set Click Listener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Login
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


            if(username.equals("test") && password.equals("test")){
                final Intent i = new Intent(this, DrinksTwitter.class);  //error on this line
                startActivity(i);
                // lblResult.setText("Login successful.");
                } else {
                lblResult.setText("Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }
    });

    final Intent k = new Intent(Screen2.this, SignUp.class);

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(k);
        }
    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong with the line:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, DrinksTwitter.class);
```

Comment: This is a horrible question, but the answer has been useful for me :) I had the same error ;)

Comment: he ask the newb question, what's the problem?! Help him..
and you @AndroidNewb should accept answer now, otherwise next time people will threat u the same..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this, DrinksTwitter.class)
```

to

```
final Intent i = new Intent(Screen2.this, DrinksTwitter.class)
```

Comment: I know, I thought about not answering. But I just happened to spot this error when glancing at it.

Comment: Where Screen2 is the name of your current class.

Answer (score 26):

Just a few lines to explain the reason why "this" does not work in:

> final Intent i = new Intent(this, DrinksTwitter.class)

The intent is created inside an other class, here an anonymous inner class OnClickListener. Thus "this" does not refer the instance of your Activity (or Context) as intended but the instance of your anonymous inner class OnClickListener.

As @Falmarri mentions in his answer instead of "this" you need to use your Activity name followed by ".this" to point to the right instance:

> final Intent i = new Intent(Screen2.this, DrinksTwitter.class)

Comment: thanks, I was wondering what was the difference with some other example I tried and why one used this and the other couldn't

Answer (score 4):

change

```
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, DrinksTwitter.class)
```

to

```
    final Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrinksTwitter.class);
```

it worked for me.