# calling a method from an onClick listener

Tags: java, this, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the containing class of an inner class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858604/accessing-the-containing-class-of-an-inner-class-in-java)

I know this has certainly been answered before, but I have been working on this for two straight nights and I either don't understand or I have messed something up badly.
I am trying to call a method with a button.  My method is only going to copy and paste so it's not opening another activity.

```
package com.example.copypastetest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PDFtester extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdftester);
            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //public void work (View view){
    this is my issue??-->Intent intent = new Intent(this, copyAsset.class);
            startActivity(intent);}         
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pdftester, menu);
        return true;}
    };
```

thank you for looking, I admit I am a total hack.  The only reason I made it this far is this website, first question, im sure of many but hopefully someone can help.  I am not trying to be a vampire but I really am looking for the correct answer here if there is a page i can read to understand what i did wrong i am all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: This has **definitely** been answered already. Just use `PDFtester.this` instead of `this`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want... If you want to copy/paste, then why are you creating an Intent... and what is this class: copyAsset?

Comment: why is it PDFtester?  I honestly have 6+ hours in this.......

Comment: copy a folder to the sdcard, use the pdf in it, then wipe the folder when done.

Comment: @user2002272 The compiler must have given you an error, like this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487911/the-constructor-intentnew-view-onclicklistener-classdrinkstwitter-is-un) question.

Comment: Firstly you should be clear what exactly you want to do, you are messing up the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //public void work (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(PDFtester.this, copyAsset.class);
        startActivity(intent);}         
    }
```

Note :- Interfaces like `OnClickListener`,`OnTouchListener` etc don't use `this` for getting `Context` try to use `YourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: First of all thank you to  edwin.  When i created the new class I had put it in the default package, hence all of my "RED"  I moved it from the "Default Package" to com.example.mypackagename. and what do you know.  thanks again.

Comment: take care with Manifest.xml while adding activities to it

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //public void work (View view){
this is my issue??-->Intent intent = new Intent(PDFtester.this, copyAsset.class);
        startActivity(intent);}         
    }

 // define the scope as PDFtester.this
```